# Uso de la variable local no asignada

Tags: c#

Ejecuto el siguiente método:

```
static bool elimino(int[] lista, string[] nombre, string nom, ref int tope) 
    {

        Console.Write("Nombre");
        nom = Console.ReadLine()
        bool e = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < tope; i++)
        {
            if (nom == nombre[i])
            {
                for (int j = i; j < tope - 1; j++)
                {
                    lista[j] = lista[tope - 1];
                    nombre[j] = nombre[j - 1];
                    tope--;
                    e = true;
                    i = tope;
                }
            }
        }
        return e;
    }
```

Lo invoco de esta forma *(creo que es la correcta)*

```
static void Main(string[] args) { 
  string[] nombre; string nom; int opcion, 
  tope = 0, cantidad; bool seguir = true;
  elimino(vector, nombre, nom, ref  tope); 
}
```

Pero de todas formas me dice

> "uso de la variable local no asignada nom,

La declaro como `string`, y aún así me marca el error en nom, no puedo ejecutar el método para probar si funciona

Comment: El error es dentro del metodo o en la invocacion?

Comment: en la invocacion, cuando lo soluciones, podre porbar el metodo para ver si realmente hace l oque quiero que es eliminar un usuario y su jugada

Comment: Pues tendrias que mostrarnos donde invocas el metodo para poder darte una respuesta correcta.

Comment: ya coloque como lo invoco `elimino(vector, nombre, nom, ref  tope); `

Comment: pero no vemos donde declaras `nom`

Comment: @einer-santana, esto lo tengo al inicio del main `static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string[] nombre;
            string nom;
 
            int opcion, tope = 0, cantidad;
            bool seguir = true;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El error que da es el [`CS0165`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0165) donde claramente dice:

> El compilador no acepta el uso variables no inicializadas.

Aqui el problema:

```
static void Main(string[] args) { 
  string nom; 
}
```

Tiene que inicializar las variables(en este caso `nom`) aunque con valor `null` para poder utilizarlas.

```
static void Main(string[] args) { 
  string nom = null;
}
```

Comment: podria ser `string nom=""`?

Comment: Sí. Puedes inicializarlas con el valor que desees.

Comment: ok gracias, ahora que logre correr el metodo, el mismo me tira un error de outograngeexception en `nombre[j] = nombre[j - 1];`

Comment: estara bien el codigo? busco eliminar al usuario junto a su jugada

Comment: Tendrias que formular otra pregunta para que alguien te la pueda responder